# Saving URL data to a variable

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, dispatch-async

So I am trying to get a simple string of data back from a RESTful API. Here is what a response looks like:

```
Hello
```

It is not formatted in XML or JSON or anything just a simple string because only one word is being passed back at a time. So here is what my swift looks like:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        println("error: \(error.localizedDescription): \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    
    var withNewLine:NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let str:NSString = withNewLine.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.spellCorrection = str
    })
})

task.resume()
```

I get the correct data back in the "str" variable before I go into the dispatch_async() method. But when I do go into the dispatch_async() method the "str" variable becomes nil and I am not sure why. I am just trying to save the single word in a variable within my class, so if I am going about this completely wrong let me know. I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

## Edit

Okay so I should have included this the first time I posted. I have also tried this:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        println("error: \(error.localizedDescription): \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    
    var withNewLine:NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    self.spellCorrection = withNewLine.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
})

task.resume()
```

But when I do this the string does not stay in the self.spellCorrection variable after the completionHandler has finished. So my question is, what should I do to keep the string in the self.spellCorrection variable after the completionHandler has finished? Thanks!

## More details

In viewDidLoad:

```
var spellCorrection: NSString = ""
//First print
println(self.spellCorrection)
```

In the method I call later I have:

```
func spellCheck() {
    var check: String = "http://theURL.com/?text=" + condenseWhitespace(self.lastTypedWord)
    let url = NSURL(string: check)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        
        if error != nil {
            println("error: \(error.localizedDescription): \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        var withNewLine:NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        self.spellCorrection = withNewLine.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    }).resume()
    //Print after the completionHandler
    println(self.spellCorrection)
}
```

Comment: @LyndseyScott If you look at the Edit section above I got rid of  dispatch_async. I am just trying to access self.spellCorrection inside the completionHandler.

Comment: As I say in the other comment, in your code you're not trying to *access* self.spellCorrection... you're trying to *set* self.spellCorrection. I'm asking where are you trying to *access* it? Because I'm guessing you may be trying to access it before it's been set.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Sorry I am messing up the terminology. I meant to say I can't seem to set self.spellCorrection in the completionHandler. When the completionHandler finished self.spellCorrection goes back to what it was originally initialized to.

Comment: And I'm asking where are you checking its value to find out that it "goes back to what it was  originally initialized to" because that's very relevant. It may not be reverting at all... It's very possible that you're just checking in the wrong place in your code.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Okay I first initialize self.spellCorrection in the viewDidLoad method. Then I call another method that has my completionHandler in it and if I print self.spellCorrection in the completionHandler I get the correct string but when I print self.spellCorrection outside of the completionHandler I do not get the correct results. If this is hard to follow I added more code in the original question.

Comment: I think I know what's going on, but still please add the code whether you try to print the string outside of the block just so I can verify that you're doing so in the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is clear in the code you've added under the "More Details" section of your answer, i.e.

```
let task: Void = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

   // ...

   self.spellCorrection =    withNewLine.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNew lineCharacterSet())
   println(spellCorrection)
}).resume()

println(self.spellCorrection)
```

by printing `self.spellCorrection` directly outside of the block, you're attempting to print it before it's been set in the async `dataTaskWithURL` block.

An async block performs in the background, so as the code written immediately after your block executes on the main thread, the code within the async block will not yet be complete. That's why `self.spellCorrection` prints correctly inside the async block -- because at that point, the code has definitely executed; but you cannot print the updated value directly outside of the async block as you've done, because the async code hasn't finished executing yet.

So, yes, your `self.spellCorrection` has in fact been set correctly, but you have to wait until after the async code executes before checking for the new value. And the surefire way to check for that updated value is in fact by printing it within the async block.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I did not realize it was an asynchronous request. Probably should have read the Class Reference more carefully. Thank you so much for your help @LyndseyScott

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to call `dispatch_async` in the first place. You're not doing any work that requires to be done on the main thread.

Comment: When I am in the completionHandler closure I can not access self.spellCorrection. So I used dispatch_async so I could access self.spellCorrection but the problem is that when I do that then I don't seem to be able to access the str variable. Is there some other method I am supposed to be using to save variables from the completionHandler?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I did remove it. I replaced the dispatch_async with "self.spellCorrection = str". But the problem is that I can not access the self.spellCorrection variable from the completionHandler. So my question is what should I do to save the data I am getting and storing the str variable into the self.spellCorrection variable?

Comment: @user2298020 Where in your code are you trying to access it?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I am trying to access self.spellCorrection inside of the completionHandler. If you look at the code above you should be able to see where I am accessing self.spellCorrection. self.spellCorrection is just a member of the class.

Comment: @user2298020 In your code you're not trying to *access* self.spellCorrection... you're trying to *set* self.spellCorrection. I'm asking where are you trying to *access* it? Because I'm guessing you may be trying to access it before it's been set.

Comment: @LyndseyScott oh gosh sorry I am using the wrong terminology. I meant to say I can't seem to set self.spellCorrection inside the completionHandler.