# UIImage not show picture

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Code

```
  var promos = [PromoGroup]()
  var adsImages = Array<UIImage>()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupData()

    //print 1
    println(self.promos.count)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func setupData() {
    getAllDataPromos { (PromoGroup, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.promos = PromoGroup!

            //print 2
            println(self.promos.count)

            for i in 0...self.promos.count-1 {
                 self.adsImages.append(UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"https://abs.com/content/bb2.jpg")!)!)!)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

but adsImage can't show image, but when i try move adsImage to viewDidLoad and also it works, and result println

print 1 result
0

print 2 result
3

count data works if its on getAllDataPromos,

what should i do if i want to show picture in adsImage...

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense as it's currently written... `adsImages` is an array not an image view. How would it show an image?

Comment: @LyndseyScott but i try cut to viewDidLoad it works... and its array of UIImage...

Comment: OK, your question still doesn't make sense as written, but I think I get what you're trying to say... Are you asking why the 1st println and the 2nd println show different results? It's because the `getAllDataPromos` block is asynchronous, which means it's running in the background so code on the main thread may execute before the block is complete.

Comment: @LyndseyScott can u give suggest what should i do for get same result between 1st println and 2nd println, because i must get data and count data from it :(

Comment: You can't because the block is asynchronous and won't be complete before the 1st println.

Answer (score 1):

(Adapted from this previous answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28207368/2274694)

By invoking `println(self.promos.count)` immediately after the call to `setupData`and thus `getAllDataPromos` contained within that method, you're attempting to print `self.promos.count` before it's been set in the asynchronous `getAllDataPromos` block.

An async block performs in the background, so as the code written immediately after your block executes on the main thread, the code within the async block will not yet be complete. That's why `println(self.promos.count)` prints correctly inside the async block -- because at that point, the code has definitely been executed; but you cannot print the updated value directly outside of the async block as you've done, because the async code hasn't finished executing yet.

Similarly, if you're trying to display an image in an `adsImage` `UIImageView` using a value from your `adsImages` array, you can't set that image until the asynchronous block is complete, so I'd recommend setting it within the async block.

Comment: how can i show image on async block, on my code its on async block right? and i don't know how can i show image and it process on async block..

Comment: @BobbyExact How are you currently trying to show your image? Are you setting a UIImageView somewhere?

Comment: what can I just use UIImage like my code? because in another function i must return that to UIImage... but i dont know how it works if i move to viewDidLoad...